# CREATE AS SELECT * but with one column obtained from another table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I need to 'recreate' over 50 tables (in Oracle) with `CREATE AS SELECT` statements. However, all this tables will have one column modified using data from another table. Is there a way to achieve this without declaring each column in the SELECT statement?

Something like:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name_copy AS SELECT *, (SELECT col_name FROM other_table WHERE other_table.col_id = table_name.col_id) AS col_name FROM table_name`
```

Basically on all tables I have a column which needs to be replaced with the data in the `other_table` column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generate the SQL string as such:

```
SELECT 'CREATE TABLE table_name_copy AS SELECT '
    || LISTAGG (column_name, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY column_name)
    || ', (SELECT col_name FROM other_table 
           WHERE other_table.col_id = table_name.col_id) AS col_name'
    || ' FROM table_name'
FROM all_tab_cols
WHERE owner = 'OWNER'
AND table_name = 'TABLE_NAME'
AND column_name != 'COL_NAME'
```

If you want to run the above statement, you could use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`:

```
DECLARE
  v_sql VARCHAR2(10000);
BEGIN
  SELECT 'CREATE TABLE table_name_copy AS SELECT '
      || LISTAGG (column_name, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY column_name)
      || ', (SELECT col_name FROM other_table 
             WHERE other_table.col_id = table_name.col_id) AS col_name'
      || ' FROM table_name'
  INTO v_sql
  FROM all_tab_cols
  WHERE owner = 'OWNER'
  AND table_name = 'TABLE_NAME'
  AND column_name != 'COL_NAME';

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql;
END;
/
```

Comment: I tried running that, but I got: `Error report - ORA-00936: missing expression. ORA-06512: at line 14. 00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"`...

Comment: @FedeE. Well, you will have to replace `OWNER`, `TABLE_NAME`, `COL_NAME` by actual identifiers from your schema... ;-)

Comment: I did :). But I still get that missing expression. I tried running the create as select alone like this: `CREATE TABLE ORIG_TABLE_COPY AS SELECT LISTAGG (column_name_to_replace, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY column_name_to_replace), (SELECT new_data_for_column FROM OTHER_TABLE_WITH_NEW_DATA WHERE OTHER_TABLE_WITH_NEW_DATA.id_column = ORIG_TABLE.id_column) AS column_name_to_replace FROM ORIG_TABLE;` which throws: `ORA-00998: must name this expression with a column alias. 00998. 00000 -  "must name this expression with a column alias"`

Comment: Ehm, why would you do that? Do you understand what my example is trying to do? It's a SQL statement that *generates* the SQL statement you want to execute.

Comment: Was just trying to find out why it wasn't working :)

Comment: I'm trying to run `DECLARE
  v_sql VARCHAR2(10000);
BEGIN
  SELECT 'CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE_COPY AS SELECT '
      || LISTAGG (column_name, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY column_name)
      || ', (SELECT new_data FROM TABLE_WITH_NEW_COLUMN_DATA WHERE TABLE_WITH_NEW_COLUMN_DATA.ID_COLUMN = table_name.ID_COLUMN) AS ORIG_COLUMN'
      || ' FROM table_name'
  INTO v_sql
  FROM all_tab_cols
  WHERE owner = 'table_owner'
  AND table_name = 'MY_TABLE'
  AND column_name != 'COLUMN_NAME';

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql;
END;
/` but I get that "missing expression" error.

Comment: I'm just going to try this again. Are you really putting the values `table_owner` and `MY_TABLE` and `COLUMN_NAME` in your query? Or are you just pasting things here? Because you have to *replace those values* by your real schema, table, column names. The reason why you're getting this error is because the `LISTAGG()` function cannot aggregate any column names if you're not selecting any from `ALL_TAB_COLS`, so the generated SQL will contain a syntax error. If you run my first query (without the PL/SQL block), then this should be very obvious to debug.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173891/discussion-between-fede-e-and-lukas-eder).

Answer (score 1):

If `col_id` column is fixed for both of the joined tables,

you may use `user_tab_columns` and `user_tables` dictionary views through the schema to produce new tables named as "*table_name*_copy" by using the following mechanism :

```
declare
 v_ddl varchar2(4000); 
 v_cln varchar2(400); 
begin
 for c in ( select * 
              from user_tables t 
             where t.table_name in
             ( select c.table_name 
                 from user_tab_columns c
                where c.column_name = 'COL_ID'  ) 
             order by t.table_name )
 loop    
   v_ddl := 'create table '||c.table_name||'_copy as 
                      select ';
   for d in ( select listagg('t1.'||column_name, ',') within group ( order by column_name ) cln 
                from user_tab_columns 
               where table_name = c.table_name 
                 and column_name != 'COL_ID' )                   
   loop
    v_cln := v_cln||d.cln;  
   end loop;
       v_ddl := v_ddl||v_cln;                       
       v_ddl := v_ddl||', t2.col_id t2_id 
        from '||c.table_name||' t1 
        left outer join other_table t2 on ( t1.col_id = t2.col_id )';

       execute immediate v_ddl;                    
       v_ddl := null;
       v_cln := null;
 end loop;
end;
```

Comment: This gives a `Error report -
ORA-06550: line 20, column 26:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ")" when expecting one of the following:

   . ( * @ % & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem
   <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2
   like4 likec between || member submultiset
The symbol "(" was substituted for ")" to continue.
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:` error.

Comment: @FedeE. excuse me there were two little forgotten typo, and fixed, now.

Comment: Arrgh: now I get `Error report -
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
ORA-06512: at line 27
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"` hehe

Comment: @FedeE. just now I've tested and edited have a look again please.

Comment: Oracle is driving me nuts... I thought it was running, but then I got: `Error report -
ORA-00972: identifier is too long
ORA-06512: at line 27
00972. 00000 -  "identifier is too long"
*Cause:    An identifier with more than 30 characters was specified.
*Action:   Specify at most 30 characters.`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use a simple join and an asterisk to return all columns from the first table, like that:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name_copy AS 
  SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT tab1.*, tab2.column_name 
    FROM table_name tab1 LEFT JOIN other_table tab2 ON tab1.col_id = tab2.col_id
  );
```

Comment: Woudln't that 'reformat' the table column order? I mean, I'll end up having all the columns in the original table plus the new column at the end of the new table.

Comment: Hm, I see, you need to replace the column, not creating a new one. In this case, you are right, it won't work as expected.

Comment: Thanks for trying tho!

Answer (score 0):

I would try this (but I don't have Oracle SQL to test on so please leave me the benefit of the doubt)

```
CREATE TABLE table_name_copy AS 

SELECT * FROM (
               SELECT *, (SELECT col_name FROM other_table WHERE other_table.col_id = table_name.col_id) as col_name 

               FROM table_name`
               )
```

edit:
then run

`ALTER TABLE table_name_copy DROP COLUMN <old column>`
to remove the column you don't need any more

Comment: That will leave me the new table with all the same columns plus the new added column at the end of the table. Basically leaving me with another schema, as I would need to remove the old column and end up with the new column at the end.

Comment: then do `alter table table_name_copy drop column <old_column>` once the new table is built

Comment: Yeah, but that will leave me with a new table with a different schema. Basically a new table with the replaced column at the end.